# Что такое нативный код?

Tags: android, ios

Что такое нативный код? ...или язык ...в общем объясните мне суть

Comment: В переводе с английского Native = Родной.
И смотря в каком контексте это встречается. 
Если например писать приложение на Flash под Android  и iOS то это считается не нативное приложение.
А если же писать два приложения. Одно на Android NDK  для Android и iOS SDK для iOS то эти приложения можно счтитать нативными. 
Понятие нативный код - код который поставляется разработчиками чего-либо.
Как например весь код в Java SDK под Android считается нативным. Все библиотеки третих разработчиков уже нет.

Ну как то так :)

Comment: @fori1ton, спасибо. Вы мне открыли глаза :) Стока времени заблуждений. Но в тоже время код можно считать нативным по отношению к виртуальной машине?

Comment: @Bimawa, обычно так не делают. Есть нативнй - исполняемый на процессоре, и ненативный - исполняемый в виртуальной машине. Разве что если на Java написать виртуальную машину и запускать в ней какой-то код, то это будет ненативный код для JVM, а код самой виртуальной машины можно будет считать нативным по отношению к JVM. Но это уже изврат.

Comment: @fori1ton, спасибо! @nMike и Вам тоже )

Comment: Хм, по мне дак @fori1ton прав. Нативность определяется контекстом, и тот же .NET для современной винды вполне себе нативен. Либо можно ссылку на четкий и достоверный источник (а не SO и ему подобные вещи)? Может я конечно тоже заблуждался)

Comment: Если говорить о window (по крайней мере об NT платформе - 2000, xp, 7,8), то в этом случае .NET - никакой не нативный. Более того, приложения, которые используют win api - также не являются нативными. Нативные только те, которые используют специальное [Native API](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447.aspx).

Comment: @KoVadim это все вопрос использования данного понятия

Answer (score 12):

> Понятие нативный код - код который поставляется разработчиками чего-либо. Как например весь код в Java SDK под Android считается нативным. Все библиотеки третих разработчиков уже нет.

Бред. Нативный код - код, компилируемый в машинные инструкции и выполняемый непоредственно процессором устройства. Любой код на Java не нативен по определению, так как выполняется на виртуальной машине. Нативный код могут писать как разработчики платформы, так и третьи разработчики (при помощи упомянутого Android NDK).

Comment: @fori1ton, возможно я не до конца понял Ваш ответ, но IMHO утверждение

    Любой код на Java не нативен по определению, так как выполняется на виртуальной машине. 

несколько спорно, если вспомнить о такой полузабытой штуке, как [PicoJava](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PicoJava) (аппаратная интерпретация Java байт-кода).

--

А по существу ответа, что нативным называется код, который исполняется аппаратно, я согласен (хотя иногда трудно провести границу между чистой аппаратурой, микропрограммами, гипервизором и эмуляцией некоторых команд системным ПО).

Comment: @avp: а ещё JIT-компиляция...

Comment: А учитывая, что современные процессоры умеют переставлять команды местами, более того, они транслируют инструкции в свое собственное внутреннее представление...

Comment: @KoVadim, да, и это очень напоминает JIT компиляцию, только не для байт-кода, а для машинных инструкций.

Answer (score 2):

В одном слове "нативный" (от англ. native, "родной") недостаточно информации. Необходимо уточнение: родной для кого?

- Для JVM родной код - байт-код, родной язык - Java (и другие).
- Для Windows родной код - Portable Executable, родной язык - C++, Delphi и др.
- Для процессора x86 родной код - инструкции x86, язык - ассемблер.

и т.п. Многие современные приложения выполняются на "слоеном пироге" из платформ: например, написанное на Java приложение выполняется на JVM, которая в свою очередь может выполняться под (или над?) Windows, которая выполняется на процессоре x86. Каждый слой имеет свой нативный код. Код из другого слоя для него не будет нативным, например, для Windows Java-код ненативный.

Родной язык - язык, для которого есть компилятор в родной код (для данной платформы).

Comment: Бредовый ответ... Это достаточно общеизвестное понятие, чтобы в нём было достаточно информации.

Comment: @Qwertiy в целом верно, если убрать последний абзац

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно конкретней, с чем именно вы несогласны?

Comment: @rjhdby, перечитал последний абзац. Чем он вам не понравился?

Comment: @SergeySlepov тем, что я с ним в корне не согласен

Comment: @rjhdby Действительно я сам себе противоречу: пишу "компилятор" и привожу Питон в качестве примера. Конечно, Питон может "нативно" исполняться только на интерпретаторе Питона. Поправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Обратимся к Wiki

> In computing, software or data formats that are native to a system are
>   those that the system supports with minimal computational overhead and
>   additional components. This word is used in such terms as native mode
>   or native code.
>
> Something running on a computer natively means that it is running
>   without any external layer requiring fewer software layers. For
>   example, in Microsoft Windows the Native API is an application
>   programming interface specific for Windows NT kernel, which can be
>   used to give access to some kernel functions, which cannot be directly
>   accessed through a more universal Windows API.

Нативный для среды исполнения код/язык/АПИ/Формат данных и т.д. - это такой, который понимается средой исполнения по умолчанию, без сложных надстроек. Абсолютно четкого определения нет - есть некое "общепринятое" понимание, которое может разниться от человека к человеку.

Для Windows, например, нативным является исполняемый код в формате `.exe` (или `.com`) файла, который работает непосредственно с Win API. Для Unix систем нативным являются бинарные файлы (а, так-же, shell-скрипты внезапно), для JVM нативным является `.jar` (не только) файл. Т.е. если совсем просто, то нативный код - это тот, который вы скормили установленной из коробки среде исполнения(дабл клик по .exe файлу в Windows) и он исполнился, не ругаясь, что ему не хватает библиотек или фреймворков.

Нативный язык - это это еще более обтекаемое определение. Можно, с оговорками, считать, что нативный для платформы язык - это язык, для которого производителем платформы создана среда разработки/компилятор в нативный код и о поддержке которого они официально заявляют в документации.

PS На ум пришла хорошая аналогия. Уровень знания иностранного языка определяется экзаменами по нему с выставлением оценки: A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2. Но есть и еще один уровень владения языком - **native**. Означает он что человек с детства живет в данной языковой среде, говорит на нем и думает(!) на нем. Уровень **native** не говорит о грамотности человека, зачастую **native** хуже знает правила языка, чаще ошибается в грамматике и пунктуации, чем С2, но он для него **РОДНОЙ**.

Answer (score 0):

Если для запуска того, во что скомпилирована программа, не требуется jit-компилятор или интрерпретатор, то она скомпилирована в нативный код.

- Байт-код джавы и il-код .net'а нативными не являются.
- Программы на Си++ компилируются в нативный код.
- Программы на VB6 могут компилироваться как в нативный код, так и в P-код.

Answer (score -1):

Нативный код - тот код, который не исполняется сторонним (не предустановленным на ОС) интерпретатором, как в случае с C#, Java, Python и др.

Язык Java для windows не нативна, так как JVM надо еще установить на винду.
Но на андроиде Java нативна, ибо JVM там изначально стоит и все приложения ее используют.

Для *Android* - **Java, Kotlin**

Для *iOs* - **Obj-C , Swift**

Comment: Глупости пишете. Нативный код - код, который исполняется на процессоре непосредственно.